# ISAPI rewrite works first time only

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-6, isapi

**The Software components**

- Win 2003 (Hopefully not for much longer)
- ISAPI rewrite v2.x (http://www.isapirewrite.com/)
- IIS 6.0 (with ISAPI rewrite added to it's list of ISAPI filters)
- Apache (2.2)

**The configuration**

- Apache is running on port 8080
- IIS has a site configured to recognise www.mysite.com
- The hosts file redirects www.mysite.com to 127.0.0.1
- A httpd.ini file is placed in the root of my site and is configured with the following string

  RewriteProxy (/google) http\://google.com/ [I,U]

**The Process**

- Remove entry from httpd.ini
- Address http://www.mysite.com/google via a browser (I have been using IE)

Witness a 404 (Correct as there is no redirect in place)

- Replace the removed entry and save.
- Hit F5 (refresh) in browser

Witness a redirect to google homepage. (Note: URL still shows http://www.mysite.com/google)

Again this is correct so far.

- Hit F5 once more (Note: No other changes.)

Witness a failure: "The requested resource could not be found."

Successive repetitions of :

- Remove entry
- Refresh Browser
- Witness IIS 404 failure
- Replace Entry
- Refresh Browser
- Witness Success

Work great, but need to be repeated for every resource each time the resource is addressed.

Clearly this is not acceptable.

**Can anyone shed light on why this might be happening and how I can introduce some consistency?**

Comment: Have you solved this problem?